# How do I fix db2prereqcheck hanging and not responding?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

When I run

```
./db2prereqcheck -i -v 11.5.8.0
```

there is no answer from the server. It hangs and is not responding.

What can be the problem?

The machine runs on AIX 7.2.

There is the same effect (not responding) when I run:

```
db2 list applications
```

But, if I run:

```
db2 list db directory
```

or

```
db2pd -db DBNAME -apinfo
```

I get the expected output. I ran it with export LC_ALL and the result is the same:

```
14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
Reading DB2 prerequisites from DB2prereqs.xml
Scanning line :   <MinPowerLevel>7</MinPowerLevel>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinPowerLevel]=7
Scanning line :   <MinOSVersion>7</MinOSVersion>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinOSVersion]=7
Scanning line :   <MinOSRelease>2</MinOSRelease>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinOSRelease]=2
Scanning line :   <TLSP value="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[TLSP]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[TLSP]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 2
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition matched
Scanning line :   <MinTL>3</MinTL>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinTL]=3
Scanning line :   <MinSP>3</MinSP>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinSP]=3
Scanning line :   </TLSP>
Scanning line :   <DDRIBFirmware>0x2000021</DDRIBFirmware>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[DDRIBFirmware]=0x2000021
Scanning line :   <QDRIBFirmware>0x0000</QDRIBFirmware>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[QDRIBFirmware]=0x0000
Scanning line :   <QDRIBDeviceID>b3153c67</QDRIBDeviceID>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[QDRIBDeviceID]=b3153c67
Scanning line :   <MinQDRIBROM>000200091000</MinQDRIBROM>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinQDRIBROM]=000200091000
Scanning line :   <RoceCX340GDeviceID>b31503101410b504</RoceCX340GDeviceID>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[RoceCX340GDeviceID]=b31503101410b504
Scanning line :   <RoceCX310GDeviceID>b31507101410e704</RoceCX310GDeviceID>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[RoceCX310GDeviceID]=b31507101410e704
Scanning line :   <MinRoceCX340GROM>000200325100</MinRoceCX340GROM>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinRoceCX340GROM]=000200325100
Scanning line :   <MinRoceCX310GROM>000200325310</MinRoceCX310GROM>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinRoceCX310GROM]=000200325310
Scanning line :   <RoceCX2Firmware>0x0000</RoceCX2Firmware>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[RoceCX2Firmware]=0x0000
Scanning line :   <RoceCX2FlexDeviceID>b3155067b3157265</RoceCX2FlexDeviceID>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[RoceCX2FlexDeviceID]=b3155067b3157265
Scanning line :   <RoceCX2DeviceID>b315506714101604</RoceCX2DeviceID>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[RoceCX2DeviceID]=b315506714101604
Scanning line :   <MinRoceCX2FlexROM>00200091302</MinRoceCX2FlexROM>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinRoceCX2FlexROM]=00200091302
Scanning line :   <MinRoceCX2ROM>000200091316</MinRoceCX2ROM>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[MinRoceCX2ROM]=000200091316
Scanning line :   <xlcPackage>
Scanning line :   <xlcPackageName>xlC.rte</xlcPackageName>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcPackageName]=xlC.rte
Scanning line :   <xlcLabel>XL C/C++ Runtime</xlcLabel>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcLabel]=XL C/C++ Runtime
Scanning line :   <xlcVersion>13</xlcVersion>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcVersion]=13
Scanning line :   <xlcMajorRelease>1</xlcMajorRelease>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcMajorRelease]=1
Scanning line :   <xlcMinorRelease>2</xlcMinorRelease>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcMinorRelease]=2
Scanning line :   <xlcMinorRelease2>0</xlcMinorRelease2>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[xlcMinorRelease2]=0
Scanning line :   </xlcPackage>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLLabel>uDAPL</uDAPLLabel>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLLabel]=uDAPL
Scanning line :   <uDAPLPackage>udapl.rte</uDAPLPackage>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLPackage]=udapl.rte
Scanning line :   <uDAPL value ="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2 TL = 3">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 2
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: TL   Operator: =     Value: 3
   Evaluate PREREQ[TL] current value= 5
   condition not matched
=== Skip tag BEGIN ===
   push to stack = uDAPL
Scanning line :   <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel>3</uDAPLMinorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel>3</uDAPLMinorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
Scanning line :   </uDAPL>
=== END skip tag RESUME ===
Scanning line :   <uDAPL value ="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2 TL = 4">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 2
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: TL   Operator: =     Value: 4
   Evaluate PREREQ[TL] current value= 5
   condition not matched
=== Skip tag BEGIN ===
   push to stack = uDAPL
Scanning line :   <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel>4</uDAPLMinorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel>4</uDAPLMinorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
Scanning line :   </uDAPL>
=== END skip tag RESUME ===
Scanning line :   <uDAPL value ="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2 TL = 5">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 2
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: TL   Operator: =     Value: 5
   Evaluate PREREQ[TL] current value= 5
   condition matched
Scanning line :   <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLVersion]=7
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLMajorRel]=2
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel>4</uDAPLMinorRel>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLMinorRel]=4
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
 ==>Adding  PREREQ[uDAPLMinorRel2]=0
Scanning line :   </uDAPL>
Scanning line :   <uDAPL value ="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2 TL = 6">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 2
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: TL   Operator: =     Value: 6
   Evaluate PREREQ[TL] current value= 5
   condition not matched
=== Skip tag BEGIN ===
   push to stack = uDAPL
Scanning line :   <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMajorRel>2</uDAPLMajorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel>6</uDAPLMinorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel>6</uDAPLMinorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
Scanning line :   </uDAPL>
=== END skip tag RESUME ===
Scanning line :   <uDAPL value ="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 3 TL = 0">
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSVersion    Operator: =     Value: 7
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSVersion] current value= 7
   condition matched
   Evaluate for PREREQ[uDAPL]
   Operand: OSRelease    Operator: =     Value: 3
   Evaluate PREREQ[OSRelease] current value= 2
   condition not matched
=== Skip tag BEGIN ===
   push to stack = uDAPL
Scanning line :   <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLVersion>7</uDAPLVersion>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMajorRel>3</uDAPLMajorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMajorRel>3</uDAPLMajorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel>0</uDAPLMinorRel>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel>0</uDAPLMinorRel>
Scanning line :   <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
   Skipping =>  <uDAPLMinorRel2>0</uDAPLMinorRel2>
Scanning line :   </uDAPL>
=== END skip tag RESUME ===
Scanning line :   <pureScale>
=== Skip tag BEGIN ===
   Pushing XML Tag to stack pureScale
   Skipping =>  <pureScale>
Scanning line :   <MinOSVersion>7</MinOSVersion>
   Skipping =>  <MinOSVersion>7</MinOSVersion>
Scanning line :   <MinOSRelease>2</MinOSRelease>
   Skipping =>  <MinOSRelease>2</MinOSRelease>
Scanning line :   <TLSP value="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2">
   Skipping =>  <TLSP value="OSVersion = 7 OSRelease = 2">
Scanning line :   <MinTL>3</MinTL>
   Skipping =>  <MinTL>3</MinTL>
Scanning line :   <MinSP>3</MinSP>
   Skipping =>  <MinSP>3</MinSP>
Scanning line :   </TLSP>
   Skipping =>  </TLSP>
Scanning line :   </pureScale>
=== END skip tag RESUME ===
Finishing reading XML for platform </platform>
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
sqloCheckForIOPorts ENTRY
szCmd ---> lslpp -lc bos.iocp.rte >> /dev/null  2>&1 > /tmp/db2prereqcheck.10420674
 IO Ports installed
szCmd ---> LANG=C /usr/sbin/lsdev -Cc iocp >> /dev/null  2>&1 > /tmp/db2prereqcheck.10420674
IO Ports not Available
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
sqloCheckForIOPorts EXIT
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
resetEtcHosts ENTRY
resetEtcHosts EXIT
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
 14743 : Cateory file path => /universal/db2/aix/bin/locale/en_US.iso88591/db2istring.cat
```

Comment: Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421216/db2prereqcheck-hangs-on-some-linux-systems)?

Comment: If `LC_ALL` setting doesn't help, then run it with the `-debug` flag and edit the question with output of this call.

Comment: Just run 'LC_ALL=C' ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the 11.5.8.0 version of db2prereqcheck?  do `which db2prereqcheck`, or fully qualify its pathname.  Most likely the solution will be in the information you are withholding from the question...

Comment: @mao - yes, for sure I run the prereqcheck from the installation directory of DB2 v 11.5.8.0. I've upgraded several instances and DBs of the lower environments some time ago up to this version... I also installed binaries of this version on the standby server today and did it succsessfully. And that worries me the most... The DB version before the upgrade (so now) is 10.5.0.8.

Comment: Are you running db2prereqcheck as root?  Have you seen https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6566057 ?

Comment: However, if the already installed 10.5.0.8 is hanging on "list applications" then I would advise to get that fixed first before doing an upgrade. Probably there will be more evidence in db2diag or other system logs ...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'll try to restart the instance manager and run ipclean before any changes.

Comment: `export LC_ALL=C; ./db2prereqcheck -i -s -l -debug`

Comment: I've edited the question and added the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem by follwing these steps from the [official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/tnpm/1.4.4?topic=prerequisites-enabling-io-completion-port-iocp-settings):

> Run the following command to check the IOCP status.
>
> `/usr/sbin/lsdev | grep iocp`
>
> If this command returns the result, *Available*, then you do not need to
> complete any more steps in this task.
>
> If the command returns something other than the result *Available*, for
> example, *Defined*, then complete the remaining steps in this task. Log
> in as root user and run the following command:
>
> `smitty iocp`
>
> Select *Change/Show Characteristics of I/O Completion Ports*. Change
> *State to be configured at system restart* from **Defined** to **Available**.
> Restart the server by using the following command:
>
> `shutdown –Fr`
>
> Confirm that the IOCP status is Available by using the following
> command:
>
> `lsdev | grep iocp`
>
> iocp0 Available I/O Completion Ports

Comment: You can [accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (after 48 hours), so that others know it works.